# How do I add a namespace to an msxml DOMDocument?

Tags: winapi, msxml, ixmldomdocument

How do I add a schema to an [`IXMLDOMDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756987(v=vs.85).aspx)?

For example, I want to generate the XML:

```
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
   <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="Frob" Target="Grob"/>
</Relationships>
```

I can construct the DOMDocument60 object *(pseudo-code)*:

```
DOMDocument60 doc = new DOMDocument60();

IXMLDOMElement relationships = doc.appendChild(doc.createElement("Relationships"));

IXMLDOMElement relationship = relationships.appendChild(doc.createElement("Relationship"));
   relationship.setAttribute("Id", "rId1");
   relationship.setAttribute("Type", "Frob");
   relationship.setAttribute("Target", "Grob");
```

Now comes the question of how to add the namespace.

### How to add the namespace?

If I do the obvious solution, setting an attribute on the **Relationships** node called `xmlns`:

```
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
```

through something like:

```
relationships.setAttribute("xmlns", 
      "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships");
```

When the document is saved, it causes the resulting xml to be wrong:

```
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
   <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="Frob" Target="Grob" xmlns=""/>
</Relationships>
```

It places empty `xmlns` attributes on every other element. In this little test document it only misapplies the `xmlns` to one element. In the real world there are dozens, or a few million other elements with an empty `xmlns` attribute.

### namespaceURI property

I tried setting the [`namespaceURI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763813(v=vs.85).aspx) property of the `Relationships` element:

```
relationshps.namespaceURI := "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships";
```

but the property is *read-only*.

### schemas Property

The document does have a [`schemas`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753815(v=vs.85).aspx) property, which gets or sets an [`XMLSchemaCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766508(v=vs.85).aspx) object. But it requires an actual schema document. E.g. trying to just set a schema doesn't work:

```
schemas = new XMLSchemaCache60();
schemas.add('', 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main');
doc.schemas := schemas;
```

But that tries to actually load the schema url, rather than not loading the schema because it isn't a URI.

Perhaps I have to randomly try other things:

```
schemas = new XMLSchemaCache60();
schemas.add('http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main', null);
doc.schemas := schemas;
```

But that causes no `xmlns` to be emitted.

Rather than trying to build an XML document the correct way, I could always use a `StringBuilder` to build the XML manually, and then have parse it into an XML Document object.

But I'd rather do it the right way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick is to realize the W3C DOM Level 2 and 3 have a method [`createElementNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) :

> Creates an element with the specified namespace URI and qualified name.
>
> ### Syntax
>
> *`element = document.createElementNS(namespaceURI, qualifiedName);`*

However MSXML 6 only supports DOM Level 1.

Fortunately, W3C DOM Level 1 did have a method to create an element with a namespace: [`createNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757901(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Creates a node using the supplied type, name, and namespace.
>
> ```
> HRESULT createNode(VARIANT Type, BSTR name, BSTR namespaceURI, out IXMLDOMNode node);
> ```

Thus my solution is that i have to change:

```
relationships: IXMLDOMElement = doc.createElement("Relationships");
```

into:

```
const NODE_ELEMENT: Integer = 1;
const ns: string = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships";

relationships: IXMLDOMElement = doc.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "Relationships", namespace);
```

A sucky part is that *every* element must be created in that namespace:

```
function AddElementNS(IXMLDOMNode parentNode, String tagName, String namespaceURI): IXMLDOMElement;
{
   doc: IXMLDOMDocument = parentNode as IXMLDOMDocument;
   if (doc == null) 
      doc = parentNode.ownerDocument;

   if (namespaceURI <> "")
      Result = doc.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, tagName, namespaceURI)
   else
      Result = doc.createElement(tagName);

   parentNode.appendChild(Result);
}

relationships: IXMLDOMElement = AddElementNS(doc, "Relationships", ns);

relationship: IXMLDOMElement = AddElementNS(relationships, "Relationship", ns);
   relationship.setAttribute("Id", "rId1");
   relationship.setAttribute("Type", "Frob");
   relationship.setAttribute("Target", "Grob");
```

## Bonus Reading

- [Creating XML with namespaces with Javascript and MSXML](http://blogs.msmvps.com/martin-honnen/2009/04/14/creating-xml-with-namespaces-with-javascript-and-msxml/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had the same problem, now with your help I got a nice `.xml` with proper namespace.